# Generically creating property of correct concrete type

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have two classes which both adhere to the same interface (IAccount). They each have a property called Preferences which adheres to another interface (IAccountPreference).

I would like a way to generically create the preferences property (ie a method which takes an IAccount and creates a Preference for it, without caring about the actual type of the IAccount passed in). What is the best way to achieve this?

The best solution I could come up with is a utility factory method, like follows (semi-pesudocode):

```
private IAccountPreference getAccountPreference(IAccount acc){
    switch(acc.GetType()){
          case AccountType1:
                return new PreferenceForAccountType1();
          case AccountType2:
                return new PreferenceForAccountType2();
          .
          .
          .
     }
}
```

And use that to get a reference to the correct concrete type. It seems messy though.

Am I missing a more obvious solution?

Comment: Can you change the concrete classes to implement another interface with the required property on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could move the the GetAccountPreference function into the IAccount interface, this way each implementation of IAccount would be responsible for returning its own correct implementation of IAccountPreference.

```
 public interface IAccount {
      ...// Other Contracts
      IAccountPreference GetAccountPreference();
 }

 public class AccountType1 : IAccount {
      ...// Properties, Methods, Constructor
      public IAccountPreference GetAccountPreference() {
           return new PreferenceForAccountType1();
      }
 }
```

Comment: Beautiful. I knew I was missing some obvious answer.

Answer (score 3):

The pattern I generally use in situations like this would be to give IAccount a function called "CreateDefaultPreferences" that creates and returns an an instance of IAccountPreference of the correct sub type for that kind of account.

Comment: example code would greately increase the value of your answer

Comment: At this point any example I would give would be almost identical to  what @mreyeros already gave.  Not being one to copy other people's work, I'll just refer everyone to his excellent example.